# Force enable encryption for portable SD card

Tags: adb, security, sd-card, encryption

There should be an option to encrypt SD card (formatted as portable) in the settings, but some manufacturers disable it while some (e.g. Samsung) have it enabled. If that is a built-in Android feature and not a custom thing added by manufacturers, is there a way to force enable it even if the manufacturer has hidden that setting? Maybe something using adb?

For example, [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/enable-adoptable-storage-no-root-needed.3615882/) has some instructions on force enabling adoptable storage that has been disabled by the manufacturer. I was wondering if something similar can be done for portable SD card encryption as well.

A non-root process would be nicer, although root-only solutions are welcome as well.

And adoptable storage is not an option for me. I tried it, and it didn't turn out to be reliable. I just want to expand my phone storage using an SD card while also having the data encrypted. Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge encryption for SD-card is only available for adapted storage. This is the first time I heard about encryption for SD in portable mode. Therefore I would assume this is a Samsung specific modification.

Comment: @Robert Oh so that's not a standard Android feature? That's a bummer. Even more disappointing as it's so easy to do in Linux which Android is based on. Thanks for the info.